# Реализация RSA шифрования на PHP

Tags: php, javascript, шифрование, rsa

Всем привет, пишу бота, который будет входить в аккаунт на одном сайте, там стоит шифрования пароля через RSA (видимо, чтобы в запросе его не было - для обеспечения безопасности).
Я порылся в скриптах сайта, там алгоритм следующий:
Делаем запрос на сервер /getrsakey/, получаем некий ключ (publickey_mod_ и какой-то дополнительный параметр publickey_exp (срок действия, наверно, он был таким - "010001" - но я не смотрел, изменяется ли он когда-либо), ответ примерно такой.
Далее скрипт выполняет шифрование по ключу и этому доп параметру:

```
var pubKey = RSA.getPublicKey(results.publickey_mod, results.publickey_exp);
```

Потом шифрует пароль, полученный из формы:

```
var encryptedPassword = RSA.encrypt(password, pubKey);
```

Вопрос следующий, как реализовать это на PHP? Порыв в интернете, я не нашел реализацию метода getPublicKey с двумя параметрами. Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: А что, простите, эта getPublicKey должна делать?

Comment: Порылся в скриптах, там такой код
var RSAPublicKey = function($modulus_hex, $encryptionExponent_hex) {
 this.modulus = new BigInteger( $modulus_hex, 16);
 this.encryptionExponent = new BigInteger( $encryptionExponent_hex, 16);
};

Comment: А делать она что должна, функция эта?

Comment: Выполнил скрипт в консоли, выдает объект с элементами encryptionExponent и modulus, у обоих тип BigInteger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**publickey_mod** - это модуль, а **publickey_exp** - это экспонента. Эти компоненты и образуют публичный ключ.

При помощи библиотеки [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) вы можете превратить эти компоненты в в объект, который можете использовать в дальнейшем.

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

// это модуль
$modulus = 'yEQs2LxSHBZgZCH0rRQQy9kmry8g2tNhQL1B9f5azNz9Ce9pXPgSRjVUo1B9Ggb/FK3jy41wWd2IfS6rse3vBzRsabMj29CVODM/19yZPmwEmjJHCgYd+AA2qweKZanDp4FLsSw/kyV5WoPN16GHEMLmLGkJFNIWtzzH5jV+S80=';
// это экспонента
$exponent = 'AQAB';

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

$modulus = new Math_BigInteger(base64_decode($modulus), 256);
$exponent = new Math_BigInteger(base64_decode($exponent), 256);

$rsa->loadKey(array('n' => $modulus, 'e' => $exponent));
$rsa->setPublicKey();

echo $rsa->getPublicKey();
```

Comment: Вообще N и E и являются открытым ключом, поскольку их достаточно для шифрования данных...

Comment: я это знаю, но вопрошающий видимо нет

Comment: Просто тавтология: ключ превратить в ключ...

Comment: если вы можете предложить более понятную формулировку, то просто исправьте ответ.

Comment: Вот скрипт ребят, поправьте меня, пожалуйста, если я ошибся в вопросе https://pastebin.com/tCSszi4u